# Toast Message Showing Continiously when Rapidly Click Button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here I am showing toast message in Xamarin Forms Android

My Code:
Inside my Android Class

```
public void ShortAlert(string message)
{            
    Toast.MakeText(Forms.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();            
}
```

I am showing this toast message when user click on A Button.But When user rapidly click the button then it will shoing continiously(5 times button click showung toast 5 times).
so I want if the user click on this button second time then previous toast should be cancel.
How to do this in Xamarin form android?

Comment: So you just want to show this toast once and never again?

Comment: No No.I want that if user rapidly click a button then it only show one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cancelling the `Toast` than it wont show on screen for a long time

```
public void ShowToast(string message)
{
    if (objToast!= null)
    {
        objToast.Cancel();
    }
    objToast = Toast.MakeText(Forms.Context, message, ToastLength.Short);
    objToast.Show();
}
```

Declare `objToast` on class level like this

```
private Toast objToast;
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the Toast itself, but with the Command or Event which is being fired when the button is tapped.

What MVVM framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the effective time of a click, for example, only the first click is valid for multiple clicks within 3 seconds,so you could change the code like this :

```
public static int MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME = 3000;//the effective time
private long lastClickTime = 0;

public void ShortAlert(string message)
   {            
       long currentTime = Calendar.Instance.TimeInMillis;
       if (currentTime - lastClickTime > MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME)
           {
             lastClickTime = currentTime;
             Toast.MakeText(Forms.Context, message, ToastLength.Short).Show();    
           }        
   }
```